# Cpanel not linking CSS file to PHP file

Tags: css

When I test my php files on a local server all the effects from the CSS folder work. But when I upload the PHP files to Cpanel only the boilerplate works. How can I fix this so that the effects work inside the body again, when I use Cpanel? I'm also using bootstrap if that helps...

I have tried everything, my CSS seems to work on my other website and have tried using that website to debug but nothing works.cs

Comment: First, check that you can access your css file from the browser. I guess that you are just pointing to the wrong place of the css file in your code.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your post needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

1.Verify file paths: Check that the file paths for both your PHP file and CSS file are correct. Ensure that the paths are relative to the root directory or the location of your PHP file.

2.Check file permissions: Ensure that the CSS file has proper permissions set. The file should be readable by the web server. Typically, a permission of 644 or 755 should work.

3.Confirm file inclusion: In your PHP file, verify that you have correctly included the CSS file using the appropriate HTML link tag. The link tag should reference the correct file path and the correct file type, like this:

```
**<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/your/css-file.css">**
```

Comment: It's a style.php file, using  <?php
header('Content-type: text/css; charset:UTF-8');
?> at the start. Should I change it to a style.css file?